# Making time in the app go down when closed/in background plus sending notifications

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background

I want my app to keep the countdown going once the app goes into background, and when it reaches a certain  number, lets say 10 hours left, it sends the user a notification saying that

This is the code I am using so far 
I googled some stuff however it seems way too advanced to what I know so far with app saving  and checking time later, are there any good tutorials, or does anybody know how can i solve that issue?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


 public var streakNumber = 0

 public var activated = false


//Labels
@IBOutlet var streakNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var remainingTimeTextLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var remainingTimeNumberLabel: UILabel!
//Buttons
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
    Activate()

}
@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
   // Deactivate()
}

//Timer
var timer = Timer()
var seconds = 59
var minutes = 59
var hours = 47


//END
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func Activate (){

    if activated == false {
        streakNumber += 1
    }
    activated = true
    streakNumberLabel.text = String(streakNumber)
}
func Deactivate (){
    ActivTimer()

    if activated == true{
        activated = false
    }
}
@objc func Clock(){
    seconds = seconds-1
    if seconds == -1{
        seconds = 59
        minutes = minutes-1
    }
    if minutes  == -1{
        minutes  = 59
        hours = hours-1
    }
    remainingTimeNumberLabel.text = (String(hours) + ":" + String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds))
    if seconds == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 {

        timer.invalidate()

    }
}
func ActivTimer(){
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.Clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

 }
```

Comment: You should move your logic into _AppDelegate_, `applicationDidEnterBackground` method

Comment: can you epxlain how with a simple example?

Comment: An app in iOS cannot remain indefinitely active when in background. Your goal can be reached if your app uses a server that's configured to send push notification.

Comment: You will need to schedule a local notification for the appropriate time in the application delegate function. If you app returns to the foreground before that time, cancel the scheduled notification and resume your countdown.